# How can I replace all instances of a specified string in a text file with another string?

Tags: mac-osx, command-line-interface, text, search-and-replace

I have a file a.txt. I would like to replace all instances of "1.6" with "1.5" in that file, overwriting the original file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the command line :

```
sed -i .bak -e 's/1\.5/1.6/g' /path/to/file
```

This command replace in the file, the orginal file is saved as /path/to/file.bak

Answer (score 7):

You can use sed for that:

```
sed 's/1\.5/1\.6/g' /path/to/file | tee output
```

also if you are inside an editor like vim, you can do that :

```
vim /path/to/file
:%s/1\.5/1\.6/g
```

In emacs :

```
emacs /path/to/file
M-x replace-string
```